# R data table -- create a variable sequenced conditional by other variable

Tags: r, data.table

I'm relatively new to R and data tables and I think what I'm asking for shouldn't be too difficult.

I have some data:

```
test <- data.table(x=(0:5))
test2 <- data.table(x=(0:2))
test3 <- data.table(x=(0:4))

data <- rbind(test, test2, test3)
```

I ultimately want to create a new variable that will be my grouping variable and with this data set, I'll end up with 3 groups. The first group will be the values 0 to 5, the second group will be values 0 to 1 and the third group will be values 0 to 4. In other words, every time there's a 0 in my original column "x", I want to start a new group. These grouping variables will be numeric: 1, 2, 3.

I've tried:

```
data <- data[, grouping_variable := sequence(.N), by=c("x")]
```

You'll see that it's close but it's not quite right. Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: maybe something like `data[, g := cumsum(x==0L)]`

Comment: @chinsoon12, perhaps post that as an answer?

Comment: @chinsoon12, this is it!! Wow crazy i spent 4 hours trying to figure this out, and I was looking for such a simple line of code. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

```
test <- data.table(x=(0:5))
test2 <- data.table(x=(0:2))
test3 <- data.table(x=(0:4))

data <- list(test, test2, test3)
rbindlist(data,idcol = 'id')
    id x
 1:  1 0
 2:  1 1
 3:  1 2
 4:  1 3
 5:  1 4
 6:  1 5
 7:  2 0
 8:  2 1
 9:  2 2
10:  3 0
11:  3 1
12:  3 2
13:  3 3
14:  3 4
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @onyambu. My example data was just for ease of portraying the issue. Unfortunately, the data set I'm working with has about 100k rows and I'm not building it myself. Otherwise, what you commented would work.

Comment: How do you want to create the grouping variable??